# latex-generated PDF has errors in Adobe Acrobat even though it opens fine in the Chrome PDF viewer and Mac OS X Preview

Tags: graphics, pdftex, luatex, adobe, acrobat

I've generated the following PDF using pdflatex:
https://ofir.io/train_short_test_long.pdf

It can be viewed perfectly fine if opened in the Chrome PDF viewer or in Preview in Mac OS X, but if I open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader I get the following error:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
> correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to
> correct the problem.

And what happens is that most of the PDF looks totally fine in Acrobat but the following figures are not displayed:
4,5,6,7(b),10

Which is very weird since I used the same software (matplotlib) to generate all the figures. And I use identical graphicx commands to include all figures in the document.

This problem still occurs even when I compile with LuaLaTex.
Those figures are all PDF files themselves, and if I open just the figure in Adobe it works fine. When compiling the PDF there's no errors and just 1 warning about a table.
Lastly, I've heard from a user of OneNote that a similar error occurs when the PDF is opened there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: With `evince`, I get the following error message: _invalid value for a dash setting_...

Comment: With `ghostscript`, I get the following error messages: `Form stream has unbalanced q/Q operators (too many q's)` and `Form stream left garbage on the stack, attempting to recover.` (on each invalid pictures).

Comment: Thanks so much, that's definitely more information than I had before. But its not clear what the workaround is, are you aware of any? I've been googling these error messages and can't really find a solution yet. One thing I might try is to export these images in a different format because it seems like the PDF format here might be the issue.

Comment: Not all Acrobat Readers are the same ... To localize the error I suggest this procedure on a dedicated Latex copy: 1) Divide your code into two parts A and B. 2) Delete A, compile, check with several Acrobat Readers, and repeat with B as well. 3) Repeat with the part that contains erros (can be both parts). // Converges quickly with 2^n ... // Don't forget to try an empty \begin{document} \end{document}, and to comment out some or many \usepackage declarations. // Purpose is to find hints quickly.

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you save the files as EPS using `plt.savefig('plot.eps')` instead of PDF?

Comment: The problems seem to lie in the figures on pages 7, 8, 9 and 12. Could you share the corresponding files and the code that was used to insert them into the document?

Comment: This looks very much like matplotlib is generating corrupt PDFs. Can you share the code to create one of the broken figures?

Answer (score -1):

If you have Abode Acrobat Pro on your mac, it is easy.

1. Open simply in Preview in your mac.
2. Select File - Print.
3. Select PDF - Create Adobe PDF.

That is it.

Comment: This is just a workaround. This does not correct the errors actually present in the PDF... And there is no guarantee that this workaround produces the expected result.